# Valve lapping and lubrication

Tags: engine, valve

I have recently taken all my valves out and cleaned them with a wire brush as well as the shafts in the cylinder heads.  I am now getting ready to put them back in and have several questions:

1. What indicator/sound should I be looking for to signal that the
   lapping of a valve is done properly?  I understand you should lap
   them until a certain sound comes out, which means the seal is ready.
2. I assume the valve stem should be lubed especially along the portion
   that goes through the guide.  Should I use regular machine oil or
   the engine specific oil (in my case 5W30)?
3. Should I lube or grease the keepers before putting them back on? I
   think some grease may actually make the precise job of setting them
   easier as it adds adhesion.

Comment: Did you watch [Cylinder Head 105](https://youtu.be/7GEmuQa3dPY) like I suggested before? It tells you *everything* you need to know. Watch it twice and take notes ... it's that good.

Comment: i did but some parts were unclear.  i just wanted to get a written confirmation

Comment: dude, i watched it again last night and not only 105 but all of them.  they are AWESOME !!  have you seen the one where he polishes a cylinder head ?

Comment: I've only watched 104 & 105 ... I figure with the quality of learning from them, the rest are probably on par. Glad you enjoyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What indicator/sound should I be looking for to signal that the lapping of a valve is done properly? I understand you should lap them until a certain sound comes out, which means the seal is ready.

You are looking to hear the pitch change. When the compound starts breaking down, the pitch will change from a low scratching noise to a higher, cleaner noise. It will *really* be self evident when you do the first one.

> 2. I assume the valve stem should be lubed especially along the portion that goes through the guide. Should I use regular machine oil or the engine specific oil (in my case 5W30)?

Engine oil will work just fine. It just needs to be clean. Oil which is on the thinner side is probably better (5w-30 > 15w-40)

> 3. Should I lube or grease the keepers before putting them back on? I think some grease may actually make the precise job of setting them easier as it adds adhesion.

Use some clean petroleum jelly on the keeper to hold them in place while you are placing them. If not exactly in place, they can jump off of the valve stem when you release the valve spring compressor.

**As a side note:** While watching the Jafromobile video, you'll notice he's very meticulous and clean as he's working. If there was only *one bit of advice I could give you, it would be*:

### ***Cleanliness is next to Godliness.***

The cleaner you keep things, the happier you'll be with the results.